# C++ MFC Add horizontal scrollbar for resizing window dialog box

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to add a horizontal scroll bar for resizing a dialog box.
I have already a  vertical scroll bar for that dialog box working.
But when I copied and paste the same code of VScroll and replace all related VScroll with HScroll and Dialog.cy with Dialog.cx its still not working.

Can any one help.?

Comment: "Still not working" is not enough detail for anyone to help you I'm sorry.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

following is an extract, if this doesn't help as others have already suggested you ought to post some code.

```
    CScrollBar m_HScrollBar;
    CScrollBar m_VScrollBar;
    SCROLLINFO m_horz, m_vert;

    int m_iSrcX;
    int m_iSrcY;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(YourClass, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_VSCROLL()
    ON_WM_HSCROLL()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void YourClass::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_TOP:
        m_iSrcY = 0;
        break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        m_iSrcY = INT_MAX;
        break;
    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        m_iSrcY = nPos;
        break;

    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
        if (m_iSrcY >= INT_MAX)
        {
            m_iSrcY = INT_MAX;
            return;
        }
        m_iSrcY += 10;
        break;
    case SB_PAGEUP:
    case SB_LINEUP:
        if (m_iSrcY <= (-INT_MAX))
        {
            m_iSrcY = 0;
            return;
        }
        m_iSrcY -= 10;
        break;
    }
    m_VScrollBar.SetScrollPos(m_iSrcY);
Invalidate();
    CDialogEx::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}

void YourClass::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_TOP:
        m_iSrcX = 0;
        break;
    case SB_BOTTOM:
        m_iSrcX = INT_MAX;
        break;
    case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
        m_iSrcX = nPos;
        break;
    case SB_PAGERIGHT:
    case SB_LINERIGHT:
        if (m_iSrcX >= INT_MAX)
        {
            m_iSrcX = INT_MAX;
            return;
        }
        m_iSrcX += 10;
        break;
    case SB_PAGELEFT:
    case SB_LINELEFT:
        if (m_iSrcX <= (-INT_MAX))
        {
            m_iSrcX = 0;
            return;
        }
        m_iSrcX -= 10;
        break;
    }

    m_HScrollBar.SetScrollPos(m_iSrcX);
    Invalidate();

    CDialogEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}


void YourClass::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{

        if (m_VScrollBar.GetSafeHwnd() && m_HScrollBar.GetSafeHwnd())
        {
            m_VScrollBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, cx - 20, 25, 20, iBottom, SWP_NOZORDER);
            m_HScrollBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, iLeft, cy - 20, cx - cx / 2 - 20, 20, SWP_NOZORDER);
        }


            //Horizontal Scroll Info Structure
            m_horz.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            m_horz.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            m_horz.nMin = 0;
            m_horz.nMax = m_MaxWidth;
            m_horz.nPage = rWnd.Width() / 10;
            m_horz.nPos = m_iSrcX;
            m_horz.nTrackPos = 0;
            m_HScrollBar.SetScrollInfo(&m_horz);
            //Vertical Scroll Info Structure
            m_vert.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            m_vert.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            m_vert.nMin = 0;
            m_vert.nMax = m_MaxHeight;
            m_vert.nPage = rWnd.Height() / 10;
            m_vert.nPos = m_iSrcY;
            m_vert.nTrackPos = 0;
            m_VScrollBar.SetScrollInfo(&m_vert);
}
```

Some things are obviously missing/incomplete, but this should give you some idea.